Proof of Deduction Theorem in Hilbert system
Deduction Theorem:
Let $\Sigma$ be an axiom system and $\psi, \varphi$ $L$-formulas. Then the following always holds: $\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi \iff \Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$.
“$\Rightarrow$”
We prove this direction using mathematical induction on the length of a proof, $n \geq 1$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$, which justifies the use of math. induction).
Base Case ($n = 1$): Assume $\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi$, i.e., $\Delta = \varphi_1$ (where we set $\varphi_1 = \varphi$) is a proof from $\Sigma, \psi$. In this case, $\varphi$ must be either a logical axiom of the Hilbert calculus or $\varphi \in \Sigma$; otherwise, the proof length would be $n = 2$. Since $\varphi$ is an axiom in any case, it follows that $\varphi \in \Sigma$, and thus $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$. The assumption $\psi$ is therefore unnecessary. From the logical axiom $\varphi \rightarrow \psi \rightarrow \varphi$, and by applying $mp$, we derive $\psi \rightarrow \varphi$, which is provable from $\Sigma$.
Inductive Hypothesis: Assume that for a proof of length $n$, a proof sequence $\Delta = \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n$ with $\varphi_n = \varphi$ derived from $\Sigma, \psi$ implies that a proof $\Delta'$ for $\psi \rightarrow \varphi$ from $\Sigma$ also exists. In short: $\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi \Rightarrow \Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$.
Inductive Step: We need to show that the inductive hypothesis holds for proofs of length $n + 1$. Assume $\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi$, i.e., there exists a proof $\Delta = \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n, \varphi_{n+1}$ with $\varphi_{n+1} = \varphi$ from $\Sigma, \psi$. By the inductive hypothesis …
This is where I am stuck. How do I move on to finally prove $\psi \rightarrow \varphi$ only from $\Sigma$ without $\psi$, so that I can conclude that the implication $\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi \Rightarrow \Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$ holds for all proof lengths $n \geq 1$?

“$\Leftarrow$”
Assume $\Sigma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$, i.e., there exists a proof $\Delta = \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n$ with $\varphi_n = \psi \rightarrow \varphi$ derived from $\Sigma$. By the rules of the Hilbert calculus, any $L$-formula can be introduced as an additional axiom; let us choose $\psi$. From $\psi$ and $\psi \rightarrow \varphi$, we can apply $mp$ to derive $\varphi$. Hence, $\Sigma, \psi \vdash \varphi$.
If you see other problems in my proof, please mention it. If my proof is too messed up, maybe there is somewhere a link to a comprehensive proof of the Deduction Theorem in the Hilbert calculus that also Logic-Amateurs can understand?

Wrt the question in the “$\Rightarrow$” direction.
In the Induction step you know that the porperty holds for $\Delta$ of lenght $n$.
Now consider the last formula $\varphi$ of the $(n+1)$-length derivation: how is it derived?
Either (i) because it is a logical axiom or a formula in $\Sigma$, in which cases the base step applies, or (ii) because it is derived by way of MP from two other formulas $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_i \to \varphi_j$ in $\Delta$ and $\varphi_j$ is $\varphi$.
For both of them you can apply the property and thus you have only to find a suitable tautology that allows you to use $\psi \to \varphi_i$ and $\psi \to (\varphi_i \to \varphi_j)$.
What we need is the tautology (usually an axiom):

$(\psi \to (\varphi_i \to \varphi_j))\to ((\psi \to \varphi_i) \to (\psi \to \varphi_j))$.

See e.g. Mendelson, Introduction to Mathematical Logic (6th edition), page 30: Proposition 1.9 (Deduction Theorem)

Thanks, but I realized that the proof is not induction but strong induction. I will elaborate further and then edit in a better proof here that you may check. The one I have here is too messed up.

@Pippen - nothing changes wrt to technique to "prefix" $\psi$ in the various steps.
